# adding a file into a listbox in vb.net / vb2008

Tags: vb.net

Hello i store proxys in a notpad.txt file and im trying to grab all proxys in the notpad and put them into listbox1

i am using

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Using Ofd As New OpenFileDialog
        Ofd.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*"
        If Ofd.ShowDialog = 1 Then ListBox1.Items.AddRange(IO.File.ReadAllLines(Ofd.FileName))
    End Using
End Sub
```

I click it the button it lets me pick a file but does not import the stuff in the file to listbox1

Please help

Comment: It isn't the code, something must be wrong with the file.

Comment: don't use the constant 1 to test the dialog result, use a value suggested to you by Intellisense, a readable source has advantages.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works for me, so I assume the problem is with the format of your file. How was the file created? Could you provide a link to it so I can take a look?

One thing to note, you should use the [DialogResult Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx) instead of the magic number 1 for the OK result to improve the readability and maintenance of your code.

```
If Ofd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then ListBox1.Items.AddRange(IO.File.ReadAllLines(Ofd.FileName))
```

Comment: Thanks so much works fine now after changing the line you said.

Answer (score 0):

try this example add it if you click on the OK button

```
    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Using Ofd As New OpenFileDialog
        Ofd.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*"

        If Ofd.ShowDialog = 1 Then

            'Pass the file path and file name to the StreamReader constructor
            Dim sr As New StreamReader(Ofd.FileName)
            Dim line As String = String.Empty
            Try
                'Read the first line of text
                line = sr.ReadLine()
                'Continue to read until you reach end of file
                While line IsNot Nothing
                    Me.listBox1.Items.Add(line)
                    'Read the next line
                    line = sr.ReadLine()
                End While

                'close the file
                sr.Close()
            Catch e As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString())
            Finally
                'close the file
                sr.Close()
            End Try
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

Regards